# Getting original and modified content from a table with an audit trail

Tags: sql, postgresql, audit-trail

I came across the following table structure and I need to perform a certain type of query upon it.

- id
- first_name
- last_name
- address
- email
- audit_parent_id
- audit_entry_type
- audit_change_date

The last three fields are for the audit trail. There is a convention that says: all original entries have the value "0" for "audit_parent_id" and the value "master" for "audit_entry_type". All the modified entries have the value of their parent id for audit_parent_id" and the value "modified" for the "audit_entry_type".

Now what I want to do is to be able to get the original value and the modified value for a field and I want to make this with less queries possible.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: The thing is I need to do some bug fixing in the application so I can't make any changes to the actual database.

Comment: You mean, all of your tables has the last three fields?

Comment: The `id` property remains the same across all records regarding the same record?

Comment: No, it increments with each entry.

Comment: And the old `id` is transferred to the `audit_parent_id`, right?

Comment: Did we manage to help you? If we did, please pick an answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a simple case, when you want to get the latest adress value change for the record with id 50, this query fits your needs.

```
select
    p.id,
    p.adress as original_address,
    (select p1.adress from persons p1 where p1.audit_parent_id = p.id order by audit_change_date desc limit 1) as latest_address
from
    persons p -- Assuming it's the table name
where
    p.id = 50
```

But this assumes that, even if the `address` value doesn't change between one audit to the other, it remains the same in the field.

Here's another example, showing all persons that had an address change:

```
select
    p.id,
    p.adress as original_address,
    (select p1.adress from persons p1 where p1.audit_parent_id = p.id order by audit_change_date desc limit 1) as latest_address
from
    persons p -- Assuming it's the table name
where
    p.audit_parent_id = 0
    and
    p.adress not like (select p1.adress from persons p1 where p1.audit_parent_id = p.id order by audit_change_date desc limit 1)
```

Comment: No no, for the modified versions, the value in "audit_parent_id" will always be the id of the original version, not the id of a previous modification.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now. What do you need to track, exactly?

Comment: Pure SQL does have WITH RECURSIVE so you can do recursive queries (given a sufficiently recent PostgreSQL of course).

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know that. Well, I'm stuck with pg 1.8.3 for a while, so that explains it.

Comment: @EvertonAgner, for example I need to get the latest change in the address field.

Comment: The latest value only or also the date it happened?

Comment: The latest value, but only if there has been a change... :)

Comment: Well, it doesn't matters, if the field's values remains the same across new auditings when their values hasn't changed.

Comment: I updated the answer. Hopefully, if I now understand your case, it's the way for it.

Comment: If you need more detailed queries, also give us more detailed information on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved with pure SQL in modern Postgres using [`WITH RECURSIVE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).

For **PostgreSQL 8.3**, this plpgsql function does the job while it is also a decent solution for modern PostgreSQL. You want to ..

> get the original value and the modified value for a field

The demo picks `first_name` as filed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_org_val(integer
                                       , OUT first_name_curr text
                                       , OUT first_name_org  text) AS
$func$
DECLARE
     _parent_id int;
BEGIN
   SELECT INTO first_name_curr, first_name_org, _parent_id
               first_name,      first_name,     audit_parent_id
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  id = $1;

   WHILE _parent_id <> 0
   LOOP
     SELECT INTO first_name_org, _parent_id
                 first_name,     audit_parent_id
     FROM   tbl
     WHERE  id = _parent_id;
   END LOOP;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_get_org_val(int) IS 'Get current and original values for id.
 $1 .. id';
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_get_org_val(123);
```

This assumes that all trees have a root node with `parent_id = 0`. No circular references, or you will end up with an endless loop. You might want to add a counter and exit the loop after x iterations.